# Retornar um valor da api

Tags: javascript, api

Olá, escrevi o seguinte codigo:

```
var request = require('request')
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000

let ranks = [];
request('https://shadowarena.pearlabyss.com/en-US/Arena?battleType=0&server=sa',function( err, res, body){
    if(err) console.log('Erro: ' + err);
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('.box_list_area').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find('.thum_name').text()
        ranks.push(name)

    });
    for(var i = 0; i <ranks.length; i++){
        if(ranks[i] === "YoDaSL"){
            let rankYo = i+1
            app.listen(PORT,()=>{
                console.log("Escutando")
            })
            app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                res.json({
                    msg: "Top: ", rankYo
                })

            })

            break
        }
    }


});
```

Na parte do `app.get()` o valor retornado da api está sendo:{top","rankYo":7} como faço para me retornar um valor limpo, exemplo Top: 7?

Comment: Não entendi ? um valor limpo? um valor texto? porque o seu código é para json!

Comment: Sim, então fiz em json, mas a resposta não me agrada, pq quando dou get na api, me retorna {top","rankYo":7}, como eu poderia fazer para retornar Top: 7. Usei o json por que foi oq eu lembrei, mas não precisa ser.

Comment: assim `res.send("Top: 7");`

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está passando um objeto dentro da response

> res.json( {msg: "Top: ", rankYo} )

Basta alterar a sua response atual, para `` res.json(`Top: ${rankYo}`) ``